# how to scroll to particular position on ion-list in ionic 2

Tags: list, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic2

I am working with ion-list, i want to scroll to particular position of list i have found some answers i tried them but that are not working in my case, my code is as below...

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let FM of menu;let i = index" [id]="i">

    <ion-row no-padding>
      <ion-col>
        {{FM.date}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>



    <ion-row no-padding>
      <ion-col>
        {{FM.menuItem1Name}}: {{FM.menuItem1}}

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-list>
```

typescript

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    scrollTo() {

        let yOffset = document.getElementById('3').offsetTop;
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(" Scroll to id " + yOffset);
          this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 500);
        }, 1000);

      }
```

but i'm getting error as **Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null**. can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: did you try using ViewChild to get the element instead?

Comment: see my update content is ViewChild

Comment: I meant for getting offsetTop here:`let yOffset = document.getElementById('3').offsetTop;`

Comment: ya but element id return null @SurajRao